# What is the solution of the integral in terms of bessel functions?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

Consider the integral:
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\delta|^2\frac{e^{\kappa \cos (2\psi)}}{\pi I_0(\kappa)}\cos^2(2\psi)d\psi$$
Where $I_0(\kappa)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind of order $0$
What's the solution in terms of $\delta$ and $I_n(\kappa)$

From mathematica, I get:
$$\frac{|\delta|^2(I_1(\kappa )+\kappa  I_2(\kappa ))}{\kappa  I_0(\kappa )}$$
But the article that I'm studying, suggests it to be:
$$\frac{|\delta|^2(I_0(\kappa)+I_2(\kappa))}{2I_0(\kappa)}$$
Which one is right?

Also about the following integral:
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\delta|^2\frac{e^{\kappa \cos (2\psi)}}{\pi I_0(\kappa)}\sin^2(2\psi)d\psi$$
I get this solution from mathematica:
$$\frac{|\delta|^2 I_1(\kappa)}{\kappa I_0(\kappa)}$$
but the paper has computed it as:
$$\frac{|\delta|^2(I_0(\kappa)-I_2(\kappa))}{2I_0(\kappa)}$$
Which one is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them, since:

$$\kappa I_0(\kappa)+\kappa I_2(\kappa) = 2 I_1(\kappa)+2\kappa I_2(\kappa) \tag{1}$$
is a consequence of:
$$ e^{z\cos\theta}=I_0(z)+2\sum_{n\geq 1}I_n(z)\cos(n\theta)\tag{2} $$
by differentiating twice both terms of $(2)$ with respect to $\theta$.

As an alternative, the identity:
$$ I_n(\alpha)=\frac{\alpha}{2n}\left(I_{n-1}(\alpha)-I_{n+1}(\alpha)\right)\tag{3}$$
comes from applying integration by parts, plus the cosine sum formula, to the integral:
$$ I_n(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(nx)\,e^{\alpha\cos x}\,dx.\tag{4}$$

Comment: well, then if you are familiar with mathematica, doesn't it use such identities to restate the solution? If yes what command should I use in mathematica? you know I'm not a math student and I'm not very good at math. I just use mathematica to reach to the final solution and then work on this final solution in my program

Comment: You cannot assume to be able to work with Bessel functions without knowing anything about them. Mathematica is a wonderful tool, but it is not able to guess which final form of a result you like most. Human eyes and knowledge are needed; otherwise, it would be much easier to let our machines do all the work for us, don't you think?

Comment: No, I'm an engineering student and I know about bessel functions from my differential equations course. I just wanted to know if there's a tool to show it directly in mathematica. Any way, I will add this simplification as a comment in mathematica to show that the final solutions are the same. Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome.